# Relative path of images in database depending on folder in solution

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, relative-path

I have an .aspx page called editprofile which can be found **inside of my ~/Account/ folder** . The page itself allows users to upload a new user avatar, change their details etc.

When the image is saved, it is saved into a table ('userprofiles') into a field called AvatarURL with a **relative path** like so: UserProfileAvatar/image.jpg

I have a separate page which is in the main solution directory above called detail.aspx. I had a problem with the image not appearing when I try to display it, and found out that this is because the path written into the database is relative to the 'Account' folder. I have managed to get this working by editing a record in my database and appending the extra level on top of it as so: Account/UserProfileAvatar/image.jpg and the image appears.

How do I compensate for environmental factors such as this so that different pages in my solution (wherever they are in the folder hierarchy) can reference images placed in this folder without any trouble?

Here is my code behind:

> ```
> Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
>     Dim sql
>     Dim cmd
>     Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BookMeetConnString").ConnectionString)
>     If Not fu_avatar.HasFile Then
>         sql = "UPDATE userprofiles SET EmailAddress=@f1, Description=@f2 WHERE TravellerName=@f3"
>         cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
>         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", email.Text)
>         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f2", description.Text)
>         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f3", User.Identity.Name)
>     Else
>         sql = "UPDATE userprofiles SET EmailAddress=@f1, Description=@f2, AvatarURL=@f3 WHERE TravellerName=@f4"
>         cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
>         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", email.Text)
>         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f2", description.Text)
>         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f3", "UserProfileAvatar/" & User.Identity.Name & ".jpg")
>         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f4", User.Identity.Name)
>         Dim fileLocationOnServerHardDisk = Request.MapPath("UserProfileAvatar") & "/" & User.Identity.Name &
>     ".jpg"
>         fu_avatar.SaveAs(fileLocationOnServerHardDisk)
>     End If
>     conn.Open()
>     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
>     conn.Close()
>     DisplayData()
>     SaveConfirmation.Visible = True
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: Probably you don't set the correct relative path when you save in the database. You should show that code to be sure.

Comment: @Steve I've edited my original post to show my code behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to change the path saved in this way

```
 Dim rootRelativeFilePath = "~/UserProfileAvatar/" &  User.Identity.Name & ".jpg"
```

then

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f3", rootRelativeFilePath)
```

this should work if `UserProfileAvatar` is a subfolder of your root site folder.
Instead, if `UserProfileAvatar` is a subfolder of the Account folder then

```
 Dim rootRelativeFilePath = "~/Account/UserProfileAvatar/" &  User.Identity.Name & ".jpg"
```

In this way, you save always the path relative to the root of your site. Consequently, every page that tries to load that file will be able to retrieve it through `Server.MapPath` without being fooled by the current page folder.